# blockchan.info payment processing, how long?

Tags: blockchain.info, payment-processors

I try to implement the payment processing API from blockchain.info
I created a request by the example of their website, and receive a generated bitcoin adress:

See an example here: https://blockchain.info/address/1Jv2S3iMo71c1WZEuE25Gemx7qjmqcVqNX
I send 0.001 BTC to that adress. It has already 8 confirmations atm. But when are they send to my adress? How much confirmations does blockchain.info needs?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. Sounds like you are using blockchain.info's receive payments API. This is a free service they offer where BC.info even pays the transaction fee. The payment forwarding used to be almost instant, then it went down to one confirmation. Sometime over the last month or two during the "stress tests" and the SPV mining fork it is taking about 24 hours before the transaction is forwarded.

Is this permanent? I don't know, but I suppose there has to be some take-away when you use a free service.

If you are looking for an alternative I suggest you try blockcypher. However with blockcypher they **do not** pay the transaction fee, so the receiving address will receive 10,000 less satoshis as a mining fee on every transaction.

http://dev.blockcypher.com/#payment-forwarding

Comment: Thanks @m1xolyd1an for your answer. Meanwhile I received the payments. I don't care it takes a while, but I cannot find how long it's supposed to take. I received this one in 2 hours.

Comment: @MathiasMaes I'm glad it worked out. Everything with BC.info has been wonky since the stress test and mini-fork, hopefully things return to normal soon.